# what is the best method to update and insert huge number of sql rows based on created timestamp on daily basis?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, cron-task

I have two tables A and B.Table A consists of status and created timestamp.Table B stores actions taken on Table A. (Every day at least hundred thousand records get stored into Table A).

I have to update status in table A if timestamp of the particular row doesn't belong to last week and insert the particular action in table B.

What are the best practices to solve this problem?

DO i have to run mysql script cron jobs or through java program(we use java in our project)?

Comment: according your question the answer is - yes, you have to use sql query, executed from cron, or from java runned by cron. rewrite your question

Answer (score 1):

It is a design decision, both solutions can work well.

Choose the simplest to be developed **for your knowledge** and the simplest to be mantained.

A little tip on the database. If you have many data and you need to search only on the last week you can partition your table to get fastest results.